Comparing histograms
I am trying to compare histograms.  I have 4 weeks of data from 10 different machines.  I want to see:

Does each machine have a 'signature' week to week?
If so, do similar machines have similar signatures?

Ultimately, should the data for a blue widget nailer be applied to predict the performance of a new blue widget nailer, OR are should I lump all machine types together using 1 set of aggregate data?
I've looked at using 2 methods using Excel:

Wasserstein Earth Moving Distance to determine a 'similarity score' (I don't what is good or bad)
A simple correlation of the %-values of each bar of 2 given histograms.

Is there a reason that the correlation concept is not valid?  Either way, any advice on how to structure the analysis?
